# To find condition on constant term of a polynomial.

Tags: real-analysis

Find the range of values of $a$ for which the equation  $3x^{4}-8x^{3}-6x^{2}+24x+a=0$ has four  real disctinct roots. I am trying to apply Rolles theorem but not getting proper answer. If given polynomial has four distinct real root then between its consecutive distinct roots derivative of given polynomial has exactly one root. But by  taking derivative constant term vanishes. Then how to find condition on $a?$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(x) = 3x^4-8x^3-6x^2+24x+a$. Then, setting $f'(x) = 0$ and solving yields:

$12x^3-24x^2-12x+24 = 0$

$12(x-2)(x^2-1) = 0$

$12(x-2)(x-1)(x+1) = 0$

$x = -1, 1, 2$

Since $f$ is a $4$-th degree polynomial with a positive leading coefficient, and $f'$ has $3$ distinct roots, we know that $f$ must have a local minimum at $x = -1$ and $x = 2$, and a local maximum at $x = 1$. This, along with the values of $f(-1)$, $f(1)$, and $f(2)$ are enough for you to sketch a graph of $y = f(x)$.

Now, note that changing the value of $a$ shifts the graph vertically. So, how far up/down can you shift the graph before it no longer has $4$ distinct real roots? To prove this more rigorously, use the intermediate value theorem along with the values of $f(-1)$, $f(1)$, and $f(2)$ that you computed.

Comment: ok.. i got your point..according to you what is range of a...

Comment: range of a should be so that the graph of the polynomial always cut the real axis at exactly four points?

Comment: As we don't know the values of the function at -1, 1 and 2 so we can not directly say that how much we can shift the graph.

Comment: yes you are right we can take range value of a as (-13,-8) as value of the function at 1 is 13(after keeping a=0) and at -1 and 2 are -19 and 8..

Comment: Thanking you...nicely enplaned...